# Applescript/pythonscript to open google chrome and login to a website?

Tags: python, google-chrome, authentication, automation, applescript

I am trying to write an apple script to open google chrome and then login to a website, say facebook or some other web site. 
Specifically, I need to log in to the proxy page of for my college internet usage.
I could work out to open specific URL's but then actually how to send data of login forms is a bit tricky guess.

If there is not any way to do it completely with applescript, can we do something with python script?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check this -- http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/

Comment: You can use the execute Javascript command to populate the forms and click the login button

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    open location "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031393"
    tell active tab of window 1
        repeat while loading is true
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        execute javascript "document.querySelectorAll('#search input')[0].value='some text'"
    end tell
end tell
```

You can use `.click()` to click a submit button.